# Linux Find command- exclude find based on file name

Tags: linux, find

I feel like this is a ridiculously easy question but I cannot find a simple regex answer for this. Basically, I am trying to use `find` to get a list of all files in my system with some exclusions. One of these exclusions is any file that ends in `.Foo.cs`, or any file named `FooInfo.cs`. I have successfully excluded a couple directories from my search, but cannot seem to exclude these two files. I've tried using `-name`, but would `-name` even work for this? Below is my expression. Thanks.

```
find . ! -name 'FooInfo.cs' ! -name '*.Foo.cs'  -type d \( -name Foo-o -name 2Foo -o -name 2_Foo \) -prune -o -type f ! -size 0 \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.bat" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec realpath {} \;| xargs grep -L CUSTOMERINFO  | sed -e 's/$/\r/g' >> ../output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not sure why, but I ended up fixing this by changing the order of what I'm excluding. Instead of excluding at the very beginning, the following worked (moving the `! -name '.FOO.cs'` and `! -name '.fooinfo.cs'`  to right after the declaration `type -f`).

I'm assuming this worked because they are files so they must be flagged with `type -f`. But please comment and correct below if you know why.

```
find . -type d \( -name Foo-o -name 2Foo -o -name 2_Foo \) -prune -o -type f ! -size 0 ! -name 'FooInfo.cs' ! -name '*.Foo.cs'   \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.bat" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec realpath {} \;| xargs grep -L CUSTOMERINFO  | sed -e 's/$/\r/g' >> ../output.txt
```